# The request body contains invalid JSON in PHP CURL Request (Discord Webhook)

Tags: php, discord, webhooks

im trying to upload image to discord webhook about 2 hrs.
Now trying like this but didn't works i got these errors:

```
{"code": 50109, "message": "The request body contains invalid JSON."}"
```

I'm trying to upload my local file with curl.

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
$ch = curl_init("https://discord.com/api/webhooks/xx/xx");
$payload = array();
$handle = fopen("cat.png", "r");
$data = fread($handle, filesize("cat.png"));
$payload['files[]'] = $data;
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($payload) );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
var_dump($result);
?>
```

Comment: Can you show us what the json you want to send should look like? Because this: `$payload['files[]'] = $data;` loos a bit odd. Are you sure that they don't mean that `files` should be an array? Like: `{"files": [....]}`? Your current code will generate json looking like this: `{"files[]": "..."}`

Comment: I already tried this too when i change it to files nothing be changed

Comment: So again, what should the json actually look like? Please add all relevant information to your question.

Comment: https://birdie0.github.io/discord-webhooks-guide/structure/file.html I cannot convert this article to php

Comment: _"Sending files using webhooks is only possible using Content-Type: multipart/form-data header"_ - This means that you can't send the data as json. Try doing something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54013666/how-to-post-upload-a-file-via-php-curl instead.

Comment: When i try in postman like this: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/980698807996125214/986048603166474281/unknown.png

Comment: Its okay but how can i do that thing on php? With postman works like this

Comment: Postman has a button to generate code for you ...